# C# change multiple backcolor RichTextBoxes at once

Tags: c#

Been fooling around with C# and ran into something that I was stumped on. Essentially, I have multiple RichTextBoxes that I want to change backcolor of all at once with the click of a button. I know the quick and dirty way is to just:

```
    richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    richTextBox2.BackColor = Color.Green;
    ...
    richTextBoxn.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

But for something like 100+ boxes, I am trying to aim for something a little compact in terms of programming. I was looking into using a for loop to solve my problem:

```
    var richTextBox = new RichTextBox[6];

        for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            var s = new RichTextBox();

            this.Controls.Add(s);

            richTextBox[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
```

But when I run the code, I get an exception issue of "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred..."

I hoping for a way to just change the backcolor of multiple RichTextBoxes/TextBoxes at once without having to write 100+ lines of code if I want to control 100+ backcolors at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change ALL the richtextboxes on your form you can do this:

```
foreach(var rtb in this.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>())
    rtb.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Just to pick your brain, what about in the case if you have two different group of richtextboxes (say group A and B) and only want to change one group and not all of them. How would you go about that approach?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you will have them organized, if you have these "groups" inside a different container each one (something like a panel or a groupbox) then you can just use theContainer.Controls instead of this.Controls, else you can add something to the tag of these controls and then operate only on the ones with the appropiate tag.

Comment: Well, what if they are named ABox1, ABox2, ... ABoxn and BBox1, BBox2, ... BBoxn? Is there a way to work with that? Sorry for the questions, just want to pretty much grasp this concept.

Comment: Yes, you obviously have the answer: *if(rtb.Name.StartsWith("ABox"))rtb.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;* in this way it will change only the ones named ABox(XXX)

Comment: Yep, that answers everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By using `var s = new RichTextBox();` you are creating a new `RichTextBox` in each iteration and bind them to the form/Container. What you need to do in this scenario is that, assign `BackColor` to the new `RichTextBox` in each iteration. That is;

```
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    var richBox = new RichTextBox();
    richBox.BackColor = Color.Green;
    this.Controls.Add(richBox);
}
```

In this case you need not to use `var richTextBox` array, If you are using `var richTextBox` array then your code will be like this:

```
var richBoxArray = new RichTextBox[6];
for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    richBoxArray[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
    this.Controls.Add(richBoxArray[i]);
}
```

Updates as Per Comment:

So the Question is that;

> How to change the background color of already existing RichTextBoxes
>   in my form

So the answer will be :

```
foreach(var richBox in this.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>())
    richBox.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: Alright, but what existing RichTextBoxes that have been created on my form?

Comment: So you need to Change the `BackColor` of already existing `RichTextBox`, Right?

Comment: Correct, I could just copy and paste `richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;` x amount of times, but I was hoping for something a bit more compact.